# Scaling [-1,1] for Neural Networks: Also for DummyVars?

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret

I have general question regarding the scaling of predictors in a neural network. I'm using the avNNet algorithm in R / Caret for a regression; I have both categorical and numerical predictors.

As far as I have understood, predictors have to be scaled prior to the modeling step:

> For lack of better prior information, it is common to standardize each
>   input to the same range or the same standard deviation. [...] In
>   particular, scaling the inputs to [-1,1] will work better than [0,1]
>   (http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/section-16.html)

If I scale my continuous predictors to the range [-1,1], what about my categorical predictors which are coded as [0 | 1]? Should I replace the zeros by -1?

Kind regards,

Requin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The categories are of a different conceptual type (and data type) from the inputs or the weights.  The categories are an enumeration (0, 1, 2, ...), and are typically distinct from one another, i.e. category 0 is no more similar to category 1 than it is to category 150.

The weights are on a continuum up floating-point values; this algorithm works best when those values are in the same range for each dimension (input feature) and evenly distributed about 0.

Scale the inputs as described; leave the categories just as you have them, at `0 | 1`.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.